# Calling toastr parametrized on post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the follow action in a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Config entity)
        {
            if (MainFacadeSpv.SpvCoreService.Update(entity))
            {
                return View(MainFacadeSpv.SpvCoreService.GetConfig());
            }

            return ViewBag(entity);
        }
```

But I need execute a toastr parametrized, something like that:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Config entity)
        {
            if (MainFacadeSpv.SpvCoreService.Update(entity))
            {
                **return View(MainFacadeSpv.SpvCoreService.GetConfig(), "toastr["success"]("Data saved")");**
            }

            **return ViewBag(entity, "toastr["error"]("Data not saved")");**
        }
```

How I can execute this toastr or any jquery o javascript function on an action of controller ??

Thanks !!!

Comment: What is `return ViewBag(entity)` supposed to be doing?. Are you trying to return some json data from an ajax call or are you trying to return the view after a nomal submit with an error message?

Comment: It sounds like you might be better off adding a `JsonResult` method to your controller which you could call via ajax. You can then run your `toastr` function from the `success` event of your ajax call

Comment: Sorry, I typed bad, its View ... Have you any example of JsonResult ??